In StyleDictionary with Node.js, after migrating from v3 to v4, "ts/resolveMath" transform is not found
After migrating StyleDictionary build script from v3 to v4, everything is working correctly, except the only "ts/resolveMath" transform:
Error:
Unknown transform "ts/resolveMath" found in platform "js":
"ts/resolveMath" does not match the name of a registered transform.

Part of config:
const sd = new StyleDictionary({
  platforms: {
    js: {
      transforms: [
        "attribute/cti",
        "name/pascal",
        "color/hex",
        "size/rem",

        // This is causing the error, if removing this line
        // the build will be successful
        "ts/resolveMath",

        "my/fontWeight/number",
      ],
      buildPath: "dist/",
      files: [
        {
          destination: "tokens.ts",
          format: "javascript/object",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
});

